# Group boolean values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

i have a Dataframe with a random series of True, False in a column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]})
df
```

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | True |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | True |
| 3 | True |
| 4 | False |
| 5 | False |
| 6 | True |
| 7 | False |
| 8 | True |
| 9 | False |
| 10 | False |

and i want this: (Dont know how to explain it with easy words)

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | 1 |
| 1 | False | 2 |
| 2 | True | 2 |
| 3 | True | 2 |
| 4 | False | 3 |
| 5 | False | 3 |
| 6 | True | 3 |
| 7 | False | 4 |
| 8 | True | 4 |
| 9 | False | 5 |
| 10 | False | 5 |

I've tried something with the following commands, but without success:
`df[A].shift()`
`df[A].diff()`
`df[A].eq()`

Many thanks for your help.
Matthias

Comment: You need to explain how you get the output of column `B`

Comment: Would you be able to give us more information on how the values in column B relate to the boolean values?

Comment: Couldn't understand the expected response, do you mean for each True, False combination, you increment the count in column B ?

Comment: Everytime that a `False` value occurs, if its predecessor is a `True`, increments the `B` value by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df['B'] = (df.A.shift() & ~df.A).cumsum() + 1
# OR df['B'] = (df.A.shift() & ~df.A).cumsum().add(1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
        A  B
0    True  1
1   False  2
2    True  2
3    True  2
4   False  3
5   False  3
6    True  3
7   False  4
8    True  4
9   False  5
10  False  5
```

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast. Thanks for the solution! btw, what did the ~ operator do?

Comment: @MatthiasFoerster it's a `not` operator which is used to turn True to False and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit logic with `diff`

```
(~df.A.astype(int).diff().ne(-1)).cumsum()+1
Out[234]: 
0     1
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     4
8     4
9     5
10    5
Name: A, dtype: int32
```